# How to count many _ids for the search term?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

How to make query returns count numbers of post_ids for searched names? I would like to have name and count in the resulting array.

Actual code:

```
@array_tags = Tag.where(:name.in=>[/r/])
# returns
# [{"_id":"4eb57a20b51ab102cc00001f","name":"ruby","post_ids":["4eb57a20b51ab102cc00001e","4eb57a53b51ab102cc000023","4eb57a63b51ab102cc000025"]}]
# best expected
# [{"_id":"4eb57a20b51ab102cc00001f","name":"ruby","count":"3"}]
```

Schema:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "4eb57a20b51ab102cc00001f" ),
  "name" : "ruby",
  "post_ids" : [ 
    ObjectId( "4eb57a20b51ab102cc00001e" ), 
    ObjectId( "4eb57a53b51ab102cc000023" ), 
    ObjectId( "4eb57a63b51ab102cc000025" ) ] }
```

**EDIT!**

I get it! Source:

```
@tags = Tag.grpost(params[:term])

def self.grpost(find_by)
  self.collection.group(
        :key => 'name',
        :cond => {:name=>{"$in"=>[/^#{find_by}/]}},
        :reduce => "function(obj,prev) { prev.total_posts += obj.post_ids.length; }",
        :initial => { total_posts: 0 }
  )
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to do that on-the-fly without some complex map-reduce operation.
Most probably it would be easier to add the count field to your Tag document and maintain it yourself with $inc or something.

Comment: Good idea but I have no idea how to do it yet.